# Do disc based games on the Xbox One require mandatory updates to be played?

Tags: xbox-one

Do disc based games on xbone require mandatory updates to be played? I've installed BF4 with no problems, but while trying to install Ryse and Forza 5 I'm prompted to update (7.5 GB between them), or else I can't play the game at all.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find out? You already know the answer to the stated question "do disc games need mandatory updates" - "yes, sometimes".

Comment: You are not very helpful at all kotekzot. I'm trying to find out why I've read statements like "Your new Xbox console would have to connect online ONCE in order to do the things Microsoft described today. And then you can keep it offline and play games without re-connecting to the Internet FOREVER." Can you answer that question perhaps?

Comment: Because that's how Microsoft decided to design their new console. Speculation about developer intent is off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

If it asks for update even if you`re disconnected then it seems to be mandatory.

But that are launch games which were made in relative haste so day 1 updates are normal. They were even reported beforehand:
* [IGN: Forza requires one time internet connection](http://www.ign.com/articles/2013/07/16/forza-motorsport-5-requires-one-time-internet-connection)
* [Gamefaqs: 6GB Forza day one update](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/691088-xbox-one/67895530)

So this specific games may be incomplete without updates. As you`ve seen with BF4 that is not a system policy. It appears that it`s up for developers to decide on this things, and hard for us to predict. Potentially the same can be on PS4 too, but I`m not sure.

Comment: This was very helpful. Just wish I seen it beforehand, my mistake.